# Products Delete in User Level in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am using magento 1.9.2.3 version.

Is it possible in magento we make a editor user and assign him role to manage the product catalog. editor user can only add and edit the products not delete the products only admin can delete, add, edit the products.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do this out of the box with Magento.
The permissions are not this specific. Any user that can add or edit will also be able to delete.

This functionality could be accomplished by creating a custom module though.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

The quickest and easiest way to do this would be to create a small module which adds the current logged in users role as a class to the page body tag.
Then you can use css to hide the delete button when anyone logs in who has that role. e.f if the role was "editor"

```
body.editor .adminhtml-catalog-product-edit button.delete { display: none; }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. do you know any extension for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of any, so you may have to get a Magento developer to do this for you. It's not a big job and if you really need this functionality it would be worthwhile.

Comment: can you give any idea how can create the custom module for this?